# Ant Junit testing puttering out - need the summary

Tags: java, xml, junit, ant

I'm using ant to build my java program.  It's compiling fine but when I go to run the unit test class it can't find Class Files.  I've messed with my classpath a ton and this exception keeps coming up?

The jars in lib are as follows:

- ant.jar
- hamcrest.jar
- hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
- hamcrest-all-1.3.jar
- hamcrest-core.jar
- junit.jar

Buildfile `build.xml`:

```
<project name="PillarWorkspaceHiring" default="test" basedir=".">
<description>
    Author: April Randolph for a evening of babysitting.  Uses Ant to build the junit, hamcrest java program.  
    Babysitting Kata
</description>

<!-- Set global properties for this build -->
<property name="test.src.dir" value="src/main/java"/>
<property name="test.build.dir" value="build/test"/>
<property name="main.build.dir" value="build/main"/>
<property name="main.src.dir" value="src/main/java"/>
<property name="full-compile" value="true"/>

<target name="clean" description="clean up">
    <!-- Delete the ${dir.build} -->
    <delete verbose="${full-compile}" >
        <fileset dir="${main.build.dir}" includes="**/*.class" /> 
        <fileset dir="${test.build.dir}" includes="**/*.class" /> 
    </delete>
</target >

<path id="classpath.test">
    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="lib/ant.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="${main.build.dir}"/>
</path>

<!-- Testsuite-->
<target name="test" depends="test-compile" >
    <junit printsummary="on" haltonfailure="yes" fork="true">
        <classpath>
          <path refid="classpath.test"/>
          <pathelement location="${test.build.dir}"/>
        </classpath>
        <formatter type="brief" usefile="false" />
        <batchtest>
            <fileset dir="${test.src.dir}" includes="**/*Test*.java" />
        </batchtest> 
    </junit>
</target>

<!-- Build main class files -->
<target name="compile" >
    <mkdir dir="${main.build.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${main.src.dir}" destdir="${main.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="test-compile" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${test.build.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${test.src.dir}" destdir="${test.build.dir}" includeantruntime="false">
        <classpath refid="classpath.test"/>
    </javac>
</target>

</project>
```

inflated: hamcrest\SelfDescribing.class

I get this from the console

```
test:
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which version of JUnit do you use?

Comment: @Stefan It turns out that I somehow uninstalled one of the frameworks that I needed and that was my problem.  Now I am getting everything a SUCCESS although the test: only shows just that.  (updated the question)

Comment: Remove `lib/ant.jar` from the classpath.

Comment: @stefanBirkner still there's not an output to verify what's happening with my testsuite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `junit.jar` and [hamcrest-all-X.X.jar](https://code.google.com/archive/p/hamcrest/downloads) to your classpath.

Specifically, you need `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` (for jUnit 4.11) in your lib folder.

### UPDATE1:

Please follow the steps:

1. Right click on the project.
2. Choose `Build Path` Then from its menu choose `Add Libraries`.
3. Choose `JUnit` then click Next.
4. Choose `JUnit4` then Finish.

**And**

1. Go to Preferences | Java | JUnit
2. Click "Add Package" and add "org.hamcrest.*"

### UPDATE2:

If **UPDATE1** not works then,

You can download `JUnit 4.7` and put `junit-4.7.jar` in your build path (instead of the older version). That can solve your issue

Comment: The lib directory has all of my .jar files.  Both of those ones.

Comment: is hamcrest-core-1.3.jar file is there?

Comment: yes. The hamcrest.jar has the file it's telling me it can't see.

Comment: @AprilRandolphforIEEE Please follow the steps.

Comment: If you have `hamcrest-all-1.3.jar` then you don't need `hamcrest-core-1.3.jar` because `core` is part of `all`.